# How to insert a variable into an element's and/or attribute´s value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, soa, bpel

I am using xslt in my BPEL to transform my payload into an accepted format for a webservice I am using that features a SQL command. Now I have this element in my payload which value I need to use in my search query.

For example:

```
<DocumentID>12341241123-124124-124124</DocumentID>
```

I want to use the value of this element "DocumentID" as a parameter in my SQL query. In the following sense:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

    <!-- a whole bunch of namespaces -->

           <xsl:template match="/">
              <xsl:for-each select="current()[string-length(DocumentID) >= $STRING_LENGTH]/DocumentID">
                 <xsl:element name="SearchRequest" type="SomeRequestType">
                 <xsl:element name="SearchScope" type="SomeStoreScope" 
                                   objectStore="SomeObjectStore"/>
                 <xsl:element name="SearchSQL">SELECT [Id] FROM Document WHERE
                                               VersionNumber ='{12341241123-124124-124124}'
                                               AND SecondStatement = true</xsl:element>
                 </xsl:element>
              </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, in the previous example, the "VersionNumber" is hardcoded. I want this to be an parameter overwritten with the actual "DocumentID" element from my payload.

Is there any way in xslt to take the value from an existing payload element and use it in another element's value as a part of it. And how would this be done if the variable should be inserted in an attribute of said element?

Something in this order?

```
         <xsl:element name="SearchSQL">SELECT [Id] FROM Document WHERE
                                       VersionNumber ='$DocumentID'
                                       AND SecondStatement = true</xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
```

Thank you in advance for your help, please feel free to ask for clarification!

Cheers,

Jesper

Comment: See [`xsl:value-of` instruction](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#value-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3.0, set expand-text="yes" and write `VersionNumber='{$DocumentID}'`.

In earlier releases write `VersionNumber='<xsl:value-of select="$DocumentID"/>'`

Note also that `xsl:element` does not have a `type` attribute until version="2.0", and that it doesn't make sense to set the `type` attribute unless there is an `xsl:import-schema` declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. I do have one question: What if the target is an attribute instead of being part of a value as described? for example: I need to take the value of "DocumentID" and get it inside an attribute targetID. 
<Target targetClass="Document" targetID ="(Insert DocumentID value)"/>?

Comment: You've always been able to use attribute value templates ever since XSLT 1.0: `targetID="{$variable}"`. I'm always amazed how some people seem to spend years writing XSLT without discovering this feature, which to me is something you teach on day one of any course.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this in a slightly different way then the answer of Michael Kay and I want to include it for completions sake:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <SearchRequest type="SomeRequestType" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SearchScope type="SomeStoreScope" objectStore="SomeObjectStore"/>
      <SearchSQL>
         <xsl:text>SELECT [Id] FROM Document WHERE VersionNumber = </xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="/Stuff/MoreStuff/DocumentID"/>
         <xsl:text> AND SecondStatement = true </xsl:text>
      </SearchSQL>
   </SearchRequest>
</xsl:template>
```

It worked perfectly like this!
In another situation I wanted to insert the variable DocumentID in an attribute and I did it in the following fashion:

```
<Target>
   <xsl:attribute name="objectId">
     <xsl:value-of select="/Stuff/MoreStuff/DocumentID"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="objectStore">
     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">SomeObjectStore</xsl:text>
   </xsl:attribute>
</Target>
```

I hope this helps someone! :)